# How can I show the Einstein Tensor using second Identity of Bianchi?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

The Einstein tensor given by:
$$G_{\mu\nu}=R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}$$
Can be shown using Bianchi identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the second identity of Bianchi is given by :
$$\nabla_tR_{irs}^l+\nabla_rR_{ist}^l+\nabla_sR_{itr}^l=0$$
Let $t=l$ the identity become :
$$\nabla_lR_{irs}^l+\nabla_rR_{isl}^l+\nabla_sR_{ilr}^l=0$$
**Note that:** (We'll use these identities)

$R_{rsl}^l=-R_{rls}^l$,  $R_{ils}^l=R_{is}$ and $R_{is}^{sl}=R_{si}^{ls}$

So, we obtain the following:
$$\fbox{$\nabla_lR_{irs}^l-\nabla_rR_{is}+\nabla_sR_{ir}=0$}$$
Using the covariant differentiation, we obtain
$$\nabla_sR_r^k=\nabla_sg^{ik}R_{ir}=g^{ik}\nabla_sR_{ir}$$
Multplying the framed formula with $g^{ik}$ we obtain:
$$\nabla_lR_{rs}^{kl}-\nabla_rR_s^k+\nabla_kR_r^k=0$$ 
Let $k=s$, the identity become:
$$\nabla_lR_{rk}^{kl}-\nabla_rR_k^k+\nabla_kR_r^k=0$$
**Keep in mind**:$R_{is}^{sl}=R_{si}^{ls}$
Now, Assuming $l=k$ in the first term of this equation, we obtain the following:
$$2\nabla_kR_r^k-\nabla_rR=0$$
This identity can be written like:
$$\nabla_k\biggl(R_r^k-\frac{1}{2}\delta_r^kR\biggr)=\nabla_kG_r^k=0$$
And this is Einstein's tensor 
$$G_{ij}=g_{ik}G_j^k=g_{ik}\biggl(R_r^k-\frac{1}{2}\delta_r^kR\biggr)=R_{ij}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{ij}$$
We can deduce that :
$$\nabla_kG_r^k=0$$